# If I am removed from a country, do I have a choice of what country I am sent to?

Tags: taiwan, deportation

I overstayed here in Taiwan because of an accident: my apartment was burned so the owner of the apartment filed a civil case for me. The court said I can't exit the country and I can't renew my visa because of that. If I am deported, will it be to my country or origin or would I be allowed to go another country?

Comment: The court said you can't leave the country but they are going to deport you?

Comment: Do you have legal representation? What have they advised you?

Comment: @DJClayworth In some countries, if one is forbidden to leave the country because of a court case, one is forced to violate immigration law.  After the case is over, deportation could follow, although some form of voluntary departure might be offered instead.  Richard Torres: In some countries you can make an application to extend your stay without leaving the country.  Have you investigated whether that is possible in Taiwan?

Comment: I'm guessing the apartment owner filed a civil case _against_ you, blaming you for the damage. I'm more surprised that you would be told to stay if you were the plaintiff.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus That can happen, perhaps to deter frivolous law suits by foreigners.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus probably to prevent him making a runner and not paying the damages the court has been asked to award.

Answer (score 7):

To start by answering the question you asked, most countries that deport you will do it to a country of their choice. You may ask to be sent to somewhere specific, but they may or may not do that.

But to answer some questions you didn't ask, you should be actively engaging with immigration to sort this out. You should also get yourself a lawyer who can advise you. That may seem expensive but having a deportation on your record is going to seriously restrict your travel and employment in the future. You are going to need one to fight your civil case anyway. You really want to sort this out without being forced to leave, or having an overstay on your record.

Options you should be looking at include:

- getting your visa renewed while still in the country (even if that is not normally possible there may be exceptions)
- making a voluntary departure instead of being deported

Comment: Note: countries often charge you the expenses of deportation, if you can afford it.

Comment: Countries tend to deport to the country you're a citizen of, as it's easiest (they're less likely and often not even allowed to deny you entry after all).